# .validate() not working in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

It is my first time using the plugin and .validate() method. Now I have a form and every time I click the submit button it runs with out doing the form validation. Here is my code:

```
<form class="form d" method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" name="searchtitle" id="searchtitle" placeholder="Enter the textbook's title">
                <input type="text" name="searchauthor" id="searchauthor" placeholder="Enter the textbook's author">
                <input type="text" name="searchpublisher" id="searchpublisher" placeholder="Enter the textbook's Publisher">
                <input type="text" name="searchedition" id="searchedition" placeholder="Enter the textbook's edition">
                <select name="searchuniversity" id="searchuniversity"></select>
                <select name="searchuniversitycampus" id="searchuniversitycampus" ></select>
                <input type="submit" id ="searchsubmit" name="searchsubmit" value="Search">
            </form>
```

I then have the following Javascript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit',"#searchpage",
    //this funciton will carry out the things we need to do to carry out our search
    function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".form.d").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                    required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    },
                    comments: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5,
                    nourl: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    name: "Required Field",
                    email: "Valid Email Required",
                    comments: "Required Field + No URL's"
                }
          });           


            $("#searchsubmit").click(
                    function(e)
                    {
                                          //Do a lot of processing here
                                        });
});
```

Like I said I'm very new to doing the forma validation and using the function.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5p9N5/7/) is a jsFiddle of the problem. When you click on submit in the fiddle it alerts "hello" and then it does the validation. How to stop this from happening. i.e validate first 1st and then run the function?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" ? any JS error ?

Comment: Well when I click the Search button as seen on the form it runs the $("#searchsubmit").click(); function instead of validating the form

Comment: use an `id` for your form and assign it to `.validate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole problem is your `click` handler.  The plugin already has callback functions built in that will capture the `click` event of the submit button.  Use the `submitHandler` to fire a function when the form is valid.  Use the `invalidHandler` to fire a function when the form is invalid.

You already have the `submitHandler` callback in your jsFiddle so I refactored your jsFiddle code as follows:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("hello");  // stuff to do when form is valid
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; 
        },
        invalidHandler: function () {
            // stuff to do when form is invalid
            alert("invalid form");  // for demo
        }
    });

    // remove click handler
    // use the plugin's built-in callback functions instead
    //$("#test").click(function(){alert("hello")});

});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/BTwaP/1/

[See documentation for all callback functions](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

---

**EDIT**:

[As of jQuery Mobile version 1.4, the `pageinit` event has been deprecated and replaced with `pagecreate`](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/).

**Good Reference**:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/594235

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great reply!!